# Prolog append to head

Tags: list, prolog

I am learning Prolog right now and I am trying to write a predicate `newhead/3` that simply appends the second parameter to the first parameter that represents a list.

So `newhead([1,2],3,R)` should yield `R = [3,1,2].`

I wrote the following and I am confused as to what this error message says as well as why the logic of my code does not seem to be correct.

```
newhead([H|T],E,R) :-
    L is [H|T],
    R is [E|L].
```

Or:

```
newhead(L,E,R) :- 
    R is [E|L].
```

Also doesn't work. This seems like it should be a pretty trivial operation but I can't believe that it could need recursion.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Use (=)/2 in place of (is)/2. Thus newhead(L,E,R) :- R = [E|L]. or simply newhead(L, E, [E|L]).

Comment: Adding to @false's comment, `is/2` is specifically for arithmetic expression evaluation and assignment. And a nit pick: "Append to head" would be "Prepend". "Append to head", technically, might be `append_to_head([H|T], X, [[H,X]|T]).` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
new_head(Tail, Head, [Head| Tail]).
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the predicate 'append/3'.

```
apped([3],[1,2],R).
R = [3,1,2]
```

or

```
append([X],[1,2],R), X=3.
R = [3,1,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that you already found your answer :) but I want to explain my answer too.

My understanding: first parameter is list and aim is the make the second argument head of the list.

Here is code:

```
new([],F,[F]).  % if your list is empty.
new([X|XS],F,[F,X|XS]):-
 new(XS,F,YS).
```

Output:

```
?- new([2,3],1,R).
R = [1, 2, 3].

?- new([],1,R).
R = [1].

?- new([2,3],[1],R).
R = [[1], 2, 3].
```